# laravel eloquent relations doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, frameworks

I am new to laravel. I am trying to build a relationship between two tables.

my database tables

comments table

```
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->string('shop_name','80');
            $table->bigInteger('product_id');
            $table->timestamps();
```

comments_images table

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('comment_id');
        $table->string('images','255');
        $table->string('shop_name','80');
        $table->timestamps();
```

=========================

Comment model

```
public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comments_images::class,'comment_id');
    }
```

Comments_images model

```
public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class);
    }
```

I tried to return related data like this

```
return Comments_images::find(439)->comments()->get();

return Comment::find(880)->images()->get();


return (new Comment())->images()->get();
```

None of them work!

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Are you utilizing the namespace correctly? For example, 'App\Comments_images'.. Also, models are best left singular- for example, 'Comment' or 'Comment_Image'. I bring that up because you aren't being consistent, which may be causing the error. The last thing is to use a string of the class, not returning an actual class. See the below examples, and notice capitalization and that I don't put an 's' on some things..

```
// in Comment model
public function images()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comments_Image','comment_id');
}

// in Comments_Image model
public function comment()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment', 'id', 'comment_id');
}
```

Edit: Feel free to use `Comment::class` instead of the string `'App\Comment'` - It resolves to the same thing and works better with editor navigation, autocomplete, and other helpful things.

Comment: I fixed it, I had to use the relation like this   return Comment::find(880)->images;   Thanks for replay

Comment: I suggest to do this instead : ```return Comment::with('images')->find(880);```
That way you are doing only one query to the database. At the moment, you get the comment from the database, then you get the images.